# How can I get rid of whitespace in NicEdit when there is no content?

Tags: javascript, nicedit

When I load a page with a NicEditor and there is no text loaded, the NicEditor defaults to having a content of `<BR>`.

I added check after I create my editor instance.

```
        myNiceEditor.addInstance(niceEditTextAreaSelectorClientID);
        if(myNiceEditor.nicInstances[0].getContent() == "<BR>"){
            myNiceEditor.nicInstances[0].setContent('');
        }
```

However when the page is loaded my editor's content is now `<P>&nbsp;</P>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is silly.

The solution is to repeat myself...

```
    myNiceEditor.addInstance(niceEditTextAreaSelectorClientID);
    if(myNiceEditor.nicInstances[0].getContent() == "<BR>"){
        myNiceEditor.nicInstances[0].setContent('');
        myNiceEditor.nicInstances[0].setContent('');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 editor.addInstance(editorId);
if(editor.nicInstances[0].getContent() == "<br>"){
    editor.nicInstances[0].setContent('');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try the following code where `editor` is the `id` attribute of your html element:

```
if ( nicEditors.findEditor( 'editor' ).getContent() == "<br>" ) {
    nicEditors.findEditor( 'editor' ).setContent( '' );
}
```

Comment: How will that get rid of whitespace? You will still be left with `<P>&nbsp;</P>`